# Stop memory leaks with recursive promises

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, promise, q

How do I create a recursive chain of JavaScript `Promise`s with the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)? The following code fails to complete in Chrome:

```
<html>
    <script src="q.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Don't keep track of a promises stack for debugging
        //Reduces memory usage when recursing promises
        Q.longStackJumpLimit = 0;

        function do_stuff(count) {
            if (count==1000000) {
                return;
            }

            if (count%10000 == 0){
                console.log( count );
            }

            return Q.delay(1).then(function() {
                return do_stuff(count+1);
            });
        }

        do_stuff(0)
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Done");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: is it a memory leak, or just a stack overflow?

Comment: The promises library lines up functions to be called from a setTimeout(0) handler so there's no traditional stack exhaustion to worry about. It's just eating the heap with references to parent promises!

Comment: It doesn't complete because `do_stuff` doesn't return a promise when `count==1000000`, that doesn't help you though :P

Comment: "recursive chain" - isn't that a contradiction of terms?

Comment: Closely related: [Building a promise chain recursively in javascript - memory considerations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29925948/1048572)

Answer (score 13):

This won't stack overflow because promises break the stack, but it will leak memory.  If you run this same code in node.js you'll get an error that reads:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

What is happening here is that a really long chain of nested promises is being created, each waiting for the next.  What you need to do is find a way to flatten that chain so that there is just one top level promise that gets returned, waiting on the inner most promise that is currently representing some real work.

### breaking the chain

The easiest solution is to construct a new promise at the top level and use it to break the recursion:

```
var Promise = require('promise');

function delay(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}

function do_stuff(count) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function doStuffRecursion(count) {
            if (count==1000000) {
                return resolve();
            }

            if (count%10000 == 0){
                console.log( count );
            }

            delay(1).then(function() {
                doStuffRecursion(count+1);
            }).done(null, reject);
        }
        doStuffRecursion(count);
    });
}

do_stuff(0).then(function() {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

Although this solution is somewhat inelegant, you can be sure it will work in all promise implementations.

### then/promise now supports tail recursion

Some promise implementations (for example [promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) from npm, which you can download as a standalone library from https://www.promisejs.org/) correctly detect this case and collapse the chain of promises into a single promise.  This works providing you don't keep a reference to the promise returned by the top level function (i.e. call `.then` on it immediately, don't keep it around).

**Good:**

```
var Promise = require('promise');

function delay(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}

function do_stuff(count) {
    if (count==1000000) {
        return;
    }

    if (count%10000 == 0){
        console.log( count );
    }

    return delay(1).then(function() {
        return do_stuff(count+1);
    });
}

do_stuff(0).then(function() {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

**Bad:**

```
var Promise = require('promise');

function delay(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}

function do_stuff(count) {
    if (count==1000000) {
        return;
    }

    if (count%10000 == 0){
        console.log( count );
    }

    return delay(1).then(function() {
        return do_stuff(count+1);
    });
}

var thisReferenceWillPreventGarbageCollection = do_stuff(0);

thisReferenceWillPreventGarbageCollection.then(function() {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

Unfortunately, none of the built in promise implementations have this optimisation, and none have any plans to implement it.

Comment: Excellent. I had an identical recursive code structure as engie running in node and had a memory leak that I couldn't explain.  The retention of return value solved it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @kgram thanks for the edit suggestion, that line was left in by accident.  I disagree with the editors who rejected the edit.

Comment: I was playing with these examples and if you change the timeout value (for example, using a `delay(1000)` instead of `delay(1)`), the JS Heap (at least in Chrome v62.0.3202.94) goes up and up. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the most simple implementation of what you're trying to do, if this works then there's a problem with the q library, otherwise there's some deep javascript troubles:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function do_stuff(count) {
            if (count==1000000) {
                return done();
            }

            if (count%1000 == 0){
                console.log( count );
            }

            return setTimeout(function() { do_stuff(count+1); }, 0);
        }

        do_stuff(0);

        function done() {
            console.log("Done");
        };
    </script>
</html>
```