# Is Node.js native Promise.all processing in parallel or sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I would like to clarify this point, as the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is not too clear about it;

**Q1:** Is `Promise.all(iterable)` processing all promises sequentially or in parallel? Or, more specifically, is it the equivalent of running chained promises like

```
p1.then(p2).then(p3).then(p4).then(p5)....
```

or is it some other kind of algorithm where all `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5`, etc. are being called at the same time (in parallel) and results are returned as soon as all resolve (or one rejects)?

**Q2:** If `Promise.all` runs in parallel, is there a convenient way to run an iterable sequencially?

**Note**: I don't want to use Q, or Bluebird, but all native ES6 specs.

Comment: Are you asking about node (V8) implementation, or about the spec?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Promise.all` executes them in parallel.

Comment: @Amit I flagged `node.js` and `io.js` as this is where I'm using it. So, yes, the V8 implementation if you will.

Comment: Promises cannot "be executed". They start their task when they are being *created* - they represent the results only - and *you* are executing everything in parallel even before passing them to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Promises are executed at the moment of creation. (can be confirmed by running a bit of code). In `new Promise(a).then(b); c();` a is executed first, then c, then b. It isn't Promise.all that runs these promises, it just handles when they resolve.

Comment: Just for clarification: The only portion of a `Promise` that gets executed (immediately) is the executor, so the function you pass to the `Promise` constructor. If `Promise.all` awaits the resolving of all given `Promise`s (or the rejection of one) it wouldn't make much sense, if these were settled sequentially.

Comment: They are executed in the order they were declared cause most javascript environment run single threaded. So declaring p1 before p2 and calling Promise.all([ p2, p1 ]) wouldn't help

Answer (score 384, accepted):

> Is `Promise.all(iterable)` executing all promises?

No, promises cannot "be executed". They start their task when they are being *created* - they represent the results only - and *you* are executing everything in parallel even before passing them to `Promise.all`.

`Promise.all` does only *await* multiple promises. It doesn't care in what order they resolve, or whether the computations are running in parallel.

> is there a convenient way to run an iterable sequencially?

If you already have your promises, you can't do much but `Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, …])` (which does not have a notion of sequence). But if you do have an iterable of asynchronous functions, you can indeed run them sequentially. Basically you need to get from

```
[fn1, fn2, fn3, …]
```

to

```
fn1().then(fn2).then(fn3).then(…)
```

and the solution to do that is using [`Array::reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
iterable.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())
```

Comment: In this example, is iterable an array of the functions that return a promise that you want to call?

Comment: @JamesReategui: Yes, exactly, that's what I meant by "*an iterable of asynchronous functions*"

Comment: `iterable.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve());` where can you put your code that runs when the last promise resolves?

Comment: @SSHThis: It's exactly as the `then` sequence - the return value is the promise for the last `fn` result, and you can chain other callbacks to that.

Comment: i'm struggling to figure out the reduce. Can you give a real code example with the fn1, fn2, fn3 run sequentially on an array of objects?

Comment: @TimoSolo: `objects.reduce((p, o) => p.then(()=>fn(o)). Promise.resolve())`

Comment: If you need to use the value from fn1 in fn2, for instance, then do it by letting `fn1().then(...` return a promise by calling fn2, thus keeping the chain. Like so:
`fn1().then( retValFromF1 => {return p2(retValFromF1)}).then(fn3).catch(...`

Comment: @wojjas That's exactly equivalent to `fn1().then(p2).then(fn3).catch(…`? No need to use a function expression.

Comment: @Bergi Using a function expression makes it possible to pass variables.  Without it there will be no retValFromF1 to pass to p2. Can it be done in some other/better way? 
The `return` is not needed if there is only one statement in the function as in my example. But as soon as there are more than one a `p2(retValFromF1)` is needed.

Comment: @wojjas Of course the `retValFromF1` is passed into `p2`, that's exactly what `p2` does. Sure, if you want to do more (pass additional variables, call multiple functions, etc) you need to use a function expression, though changing `p2` in the array would be easier

Comment: @Bergi Can I say that: `iterable.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())` is equivalent to: `[fn1, fn2, fn3].reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())` ???

Comment: @robe007 Yes, I meant that `iterable` is the `[fn1, fn2, fn3, …]` array

Comment: @Bergi And ... every `fn...` it is a function that returns a promise???

Comment: @robe007 Yes, they're asynchronous functions.

Comment: `iterable.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())` gave me a headache in nodeJS and seems to have a different behaviour than doing it in 2 lines, eg : `ps.reduce((p, fn) => {
 p.then(fn);
        return Promise.resolve();
});`

Comment: @HaneTV The comma separates arguments: `iterable.reduce((p, fn) => { return p.then(fn); }, Promise.resolve())`

Answer (score 184):

### In parallel

```
await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => { 
  await fetchItem(item) 
}))
```

Advantages: Faster. All iterations will be started even if one fails later on. However, it will ["fail fast"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#promise.all_fail-fast_behavior). Use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), to complete all iterations in parallel even if some throw. Technically, these are concurrent invocations not in parallel.

### In sequence

```
for (const item of items) {
  await fetchItem(item)
}
```

Advantages: Variables in the loop can be shared by each iteration. Behaves like normal imperative synchronous code.

Comment: Or: `for (const item of items) await fetchItem(item);`

Comment: @david_adler In parallel example advantages you said **All iterations will be executed even if one fails**. If I'm not wrong this would still fail fast.
To change this behaviour one can do something like:

`await Promise.all(items.map(async item => { return await fetchItem(item).catch(e => e) }))`

Comment: @Taimoor yes it does "fail fast" and continue executing code after the Promise.all but all iterations are still executed https://codepen.io/mfbx9da4/pen/BbaaXr

Comment: This approach is better, when the `async` function is an API call an you don't want to DDOS the server. You have better control over the individual results and errors thrown in the execution. Even better you can decide on what errors to continue and on what to break the loop.

Comment: Note that javascript isn't actually executing the asynchronous requests in "parallel" using threads since javascript is single threaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: if you need the results for the parallel version: let results = await Promise.all(items.map(async item => { return await fetchItem(item) })); and re the comment about not being in "parallel", if the requests call an external function such as fetching a file or api call then they ARE truly parallel despite the javascript engine being single threaded.

Comment: @twhitehead yes the engine is multithreaded but ultimately all comes back to javascripts main thread for serialization of the responses. By truly parallel, you mean new threads are spawned for each request in the engine under the hood? Is that how all engines work? Is that part of the spec? Or is that just the only way things could work? Could you point to something in the spec by any chance?

Comment: The defined async function with await inside the map method is redundant.

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy yes it is but it will be more obvious how to extend it for people new to Promise.all

Comment: Use `Promise.allSettled` if you want all items to be *executed* (and not just started) regardless if one fails.

Comment: In the parallel example, is the `await` in `await fetchItem(item)` necessary? Why not `await Promise.all(items.map(item => fetchItem(item)))`

Comment: It's not necessary but I left it in for illustrative purposes as it's easy to see how to modify code inside the inner arrow function.

Comment: @david_adler i actually think using the inner await makes it synchronous

Comment: In what way synchronous? Each inner callback will be executed concurrently with respect to each other.

Comment: A note regarding the parallel section, To the best of my knowledge - Its concurrent execution *not parallel*. -> The difference is, That 1 promise will be executed, then the next one will be executed without waiting for the first to resolve. Parallel is when all of the promises are *executed* at the same time, which I think is not possible with promises ,it might be possible with RXJS observable and the fork join operator - (But Im not 100% sure if its really subscribing to each one in parallel or concurrently just like promise.all).

Comment: Yeah parallel isn't super accurate, concurrent would be more accurate. Any JS code itself is always single threaded and happens in serial.

Comment: @RobertPenner I learned from the Camel Book on Perl that it's better to use braces on a for loop even when there's only one statement, because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 55):

NodeJS does not run promises in parallel, it runs them concurrently since it’s a single-threaded event loop architecture. There is a possibility to run things in parallel by creating a new child process to take advantage of the multiple core CPU.

[Parallel Vs Concurent](https://bytearcher.com/articles/parallel-vs-concurrent/)

In fact, what `Promise.all` does is, stacking the promises function in the appropriate queue (see event loop architecture) running them concurrently (call P1, P2,...) then waiting for each result, then resolving the Promise.all with all the promises results.
Promise.all will fail at the first promise which fails unless you have to manage the rejection yourself.

There is a major difference between parallel and concurrent, the first one will run a different computation in a separate process at exactly the same time and they will progress at their rhythm, while the other one will execute the different computation one after another without waiting for the previous computation to finish and progress at the same time without depending on each other.

Finally, to answer your question, `Promise.all` will execute neither in parallel nor sequentially but concurrently.

Comment: This is not right. NodeJS can run things in parallel. NodeJS has a concept of worker thread. By default the number of worker thread is 4. For example, if you use crypto library to hash two values then you can execute them in parallel. Two worker threads will handle the task. Of course, your CPU has to be multi-core to support parallelism.

Comment: Yeah you right, it’s what i said at the end of the first paragraph, but i talked about child process, of course they can run workers.

Comment: Best answer so far. I was so confused that how a single-threaded architecture like Node.js could run multiple promises in parallel. Thanks alot sir.

P.S. I know how worker threads are and how they work but promises are resolved by Node.js event-loop itself and not by using libuv. So the best Node.js could do is to execute them (promises) concurrently.

Answer (score 15):

[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823708/6045800) got me on the right track using `Array.reduce`.

However, to actually get the functions returning my promises to execute one after another I had to add some more nesting.

My real use case is an array of files that I need to transfer in order one after another due to limits downstream...

Here is what I ended up with:

```
getAllFiles().then( (files) => {
    return files.reduce((p, theFile) => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return transferFile(theFile); //function returns a promise
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(()=>{
        console.log("All files transferred");
    });
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

As previous answers suggest, using:

```
getAllFiles().then( (files) => {
    return files.reduce((p, theFile) => {
        return p.then(transferFile(theFile));
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(()=>{
        console.log("All files transferred");
    });
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

didn't wait for the transfer to complete before starting another and also the "All files transferred" text came before even the first file transfer was started.

Not sure what I did wrong, but wanted to share what worked for me.

Edit: Since I wrote this post I now understand why the first version didn't work. `then()` expects a *function* returning a promise. So, you should pass in the function name without parentheses! Now, my function wants an argument so then I need to wrap in in a anonymous function taking no argument!

Answer (score 8):

You can also process an iterable sequentially with an async function using a recursive function. For example, given an array `a` to process with asynchronous function `someAsyncFunction()`:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

function someAsyncFunction(n) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("someAsyncFunction: ", n)
      resolve(n)
    }, Math.random() * 1500)
  })
}

//You can run each array sequentially with: 

function sequential(arr, index = 0) {
  if (index >= arr.length) return Promise.resolve()
  return someAsyncFunction(arr[index])
    .then(r => {
      console.log("got value: ", r)
      return sequential(arr, index + 1)
    })
}

sequential(a).then(() => console.log("done"))
```

Comment: using `array.prototype.reduce` is much better in terms of performance than a recursive function

Comment: @MateuszSowiński, there is a 1500ms timeout between each call. Considering that this is doing async calls sequentially, it’s hard to see how that’s relevant even for a very quick async turnaround.

Comment: Let's say you have to execute 40 of really quick async functions after each other - using recursive functions would clog your memory pretty fast

Comment: @MateuszSowiński, that the stack doesn't wind up here...we're returning after each call. Compare that with `reduce` where you have to build the entire `then()` chain in one step and then execute.

Comment: In the 40th call of the sequential function the first call of the function is still in memory waiting for the chain of sequential functions to return

Comment: I'll refer you to this thread if you really want to discuss the nuances of this @MateuszSowiński: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925948/building-a-promise-chain-recursively-in-javascript-memory-considerations

Comment: you could add a third parameter with an accumulator of type array, and return it in the last `Promise.resolve()` - will be in the same format as Promise.all but sequentially

Comment: One thing I dont like about this way is the need to create an "extra" function (`sequential`) for it to work, in comparison to `for` and `reduce` solutions. But it could very much be in a tool like lodash, for example

Comment: for completeness, you should make `a` an array of promises, and then change `someAsyncFunction()` to simply `arr[index]()`, without forgeting to use `await`

Answer (score 5):

Just to elaborate on [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823708/6045800) (which is very succinct, but tricky to understand ;)

This code will run each item in the array and add the next 'then chain' to the end:

```
function eachorder(prev,order) {
        return prev.then(function() {
          return get_order(order)
            .then(check_order)
            .then(update_order);
        });
    }
orderArray.reduce(eachorder,Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 4):

Using **async await** an array of promises can easily be executed sequentially:

```
let a = [promise1, promise2, promise3];

async function func() {
  for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    await a[i]();
  }  
}

func();
```

Note: In above implementation, if a promise is rejected, the rest wouldn't be executed.If you want all your promises to be executed, then wrap your `await a[i]();` inside `try catch`

Answer (score 3):

**parallel**

see this example

```
const resolveAfterTimeout = async i => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("CALLED");
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("RESOLVED", i);
    }, 5000);
  });
};

const call = async () => {
  const res = await Promise.all([
    resolveAfterTimeout(1),
    resolveAfterTimeout(2),
    resolveAfterTimeout(3),
    resolveAfterTimeout(4),
    resolveAfterTimeout(5),
    resolveAfterTimeout(6)
  ]);
  console.log({ res });
};

call();
```

by running the code it'll console "CALLED" for all six promises and when they are resolved it will console every 6 responses after timeout at the same time

Answer (score 2):

[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823708/6045800) helped me to make the call synchronous. I have added an example below where we call each function after the previous function is called:

```
function func1 (param1) {
    console.log("function1 : " + param1);
}
function func2 () {
    console.log("function2");
}
function func3 (param2, param3) {
    console.log("function3 : " + param2 + ", " + param3);
}

function func4 (param4) {
    console.log("function4 : " + param4);
}
param4 = "Kate";

//adding 3 functions to array

a=[
    ()=>func1("Hi"),
    ()=>func2(),
    ()=>func3("Lindsay",param4)
  ];

//adding 4th function

a.push(()=>func4("dad"));

//below does func1().then(func2).then(func3).then(func4)

a.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the original question?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this page while trying to solve a problem in NodeJS: reassembly of file chunks.  Basically:
I have an array of filenames.
I need to append all those files, in the correct order, to create one large file.
I must do this asynchronously.

Node's 'fs' module does provide `appendFileSync` but I didn't want to block the server during this operation. I wanted to use the `fs.promises` module and find a way to chain this stuff together. The examples on this page didn't quite work for me because I actually needed two operations: `fsPromises.read()` to read in the file chunk, and `fsPromises.appendFile()` to concat to the destination file. Maybe if I was better with JavaScript I could have made the previous answers work for me.  ;-)

I stumbled across [this](https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/) and I was able to hack together a working solution:

```
/**
 * sequentially append a list of files into a specified destination file
 */
exports.append_files = function (destinationFile, arrayOfFilenames) {
    return arrayOfFilenames.reduce((previousPromise, currentFile) => {
        return previousPromise.then(() => {
            return fsPromises.readFile(currentFile).then(fileContents => {
                return fsPromises.appendFile(destinationFile, fileContents);
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```

And here's a jasmine unit test for it:

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const fsUtils = require( ... );
const TEMPDIR = 'temp';

describe("test append_files", function() {
    it('append_files should work', async function(done) {
        try {
            // setup: create some files
            await fsPromises.mkdir(TEMPDIR);
            await fsPromises.writeFile(path.join(TEMPDIR, '1'), 'one');
            await fsPromises.writeFile(path.join(TEMPDIR, '2'), 'two');
            await fsPromises.writeFile(path.join(TEMPDIR, '3'), 'three');
            await fsPromises.writeFile(path.join(TEMPDIR, '4'), 'four');
            await fsPromises.writeFile(path.join(TEMPDIR, '5'), 'five');

            const filenameArray = [];
            for (var i=1; i < 6; i++) {
                filenameArray.push(path.join(TEMPDIR, i.toString()));
            }

            const DESTFILE = path.join(TEMPDIR, 'final');
            await fsUtils.append_files(DESTFILE, filenameArray);

            // confirm "final" file exists    
            const fsStat = await fsPromises.stat(DESTFILE);
            expect(fsStat.isFile()).toBeTruthy();

            // confirm content of the "final" file
            const expectedContent = new Buffer('onetwothreefourfive', 'utf8');
            var fileContents = await fsPromises.readFile(DESTFILE);
            expect(fileContents).toEqual(expectedContent);

            done();
        }
        catch (err) {
            fail(err);
        }
        finally {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by for loop.

async function return promise:

```
async function createClient(client) {
    return await Client.create(client);
}

let clients = [client1, client2, client3];
```

if you write following code then client are created parallelly:

```
const createdClientsArray = yield Promise.all(clients.map((client) =>
    createClient(client);
));
```

But if you want to create client sequentially then you should use for loop:

```
const createdClientsArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    const createdClient = yield createClient(clients[i]);
    createdClientsArray.push(createdClient);
}
```

Comment: At this time, `async`/`await` is only available with a transpiler, or using [other engines](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) than Node. Also, you really should not mix `async` with `yield`. Whle they act the same with a transpiler and [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co), they really are quite different and should not ordinarily substitude each other. Also, you should mention these restrictions as your answer is confusing to novice programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using for of in order to solve sequential promises. I'm not sure if it helps here but this is what I've been doing.

```
async function run() {
    for (let val of arr) {
        const res = await someQuery(val)
        console.log(val)
    }
}

run().then().catch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can chain an array of promise returning functions as follows
(this passes the result of each function to the next). You could of course edit it to pass the same argument (or no arguments) to each function.

```js
function tester1(a) {
  return new Promise(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      done(a + 1);
    }, 1000);
  })
}

function tester2(a) {
  return new Promise(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      done(a * 5);
    }, 1000);
  })
}

function promise_chain(args, list, results) {

  return new Promise(function(done, errs) {
    var fn = list.shift();
    if (results === undefined) results = [];
    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
      fn(args).then(function(result) {
        results.push(result);
        console.log(result);
        promise_chain(result, list, results).then(done);
      }, errs);
    } else {
      done(results);
    }

  });
}

promise_chain(0, [tester1, tester2, tester1, tester2, tester2]).then(console.log.bind(console), console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score -2):

**see this sample**

**Promise.all** working parallel

```
const { range, random, forEach, delay} = require("lodash");  
const run = id => {
    console.log(`Start Task ${id}`);
    let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        delay(() => {
            console.log(`Finish Task ${id}`);
            resolve(id);
        }, random(2000, 15000));
    });
    return prom;
}


const exec = () => {
    let proms = []; 
    forEach(range(1,10), (id,index) => {
        proms.push(run(id));
    });
    let allPromis = Promise.all(proms); 
    allPromis.then(
        res => { 
            forEach(res, v => console.log(v));
        }
    );
}

exec();
```