# How to perform Sequential-Parallel Task with es6-Promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

```
function run(){
  console.log('hello');
}

Promise.allSettled([
    run(),
    run(),
  ])
```

**executing this code 2 instances run instantly logging:**

hello

hello

**I want to settle the process in batch. how do I achieve this in Javascript?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I execute array of promises in sequential order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100245/how-can-i-execute-array-of-promises-in-sequential-order)

Comment: sequential or parallel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallel operations with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772401/parallel-operations-with-promise-all)

Comment: I am trying to run 2 parallel tasks in loop sequentially@evolutionxbox