# How to ensure the execution order of a random number of promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

How can I rearrange the code below to output `0011223344` instead of `01234<random values>`? I'm relatively new to promises and don't know how to batch the promises in a way that the second one only executes when the first one is resolved.

```
function getPromise(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(value);
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(value);
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  getPromise(i).then(console.log);
}
```

**EDIT**

In the real scenario the number of promises is random and unpredictable.
Since promises inner code start to being executed immediately after creation, I can't have something like a promises array to iterate over, for example.

I guess that's the reason because I couldn't make it work with `Promise.all`.

Comment: if this is used in NodeJS, you could use a library like `async` that has a `async.series()` and `async.waterfall()` methods. Maybe it can also be used client-side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Node.js native Promise.all processing in parallel or sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823653/is-node-js-native-promise-all-processing-in-parallel-or-sequentially)

Comment: `[0,1,2,3,4].reduce((acc, i) => { return acc.then(() => { return getPromise(i).then(console.log) }); }, Promise.resolve());` which (slowly) outputs 0011223344 to the console.

Comment: @zero298 See my edit, please.

Comment: @JaredSmith Your solution works too. Thanks!

Comment: Give a more concrete example of a scenario where you would not know the number of things to execute before kicking off the first promise.  I don't understand how you expect to wait for all of your non-quantifiable tasks to finish if you don't have a way to quantify "all of them".

Comment: @JeremyThille - combining Promises (which is what the question is about) with assyncjs is a recipe for disaster

Comment: No, I wouldn't combine promises and Async. One either uses promises _or_ Async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Await the previous one, then execute the next:

```
 var promise = Promise.resolve();
 for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  promise = promise.then( _=> getPromise(i).then(console.log) );
 }
```