# Is it ok to use a generator function to replace a promise management?

Tags: javascript, promise, generator

For this code example, you have to imagine a series of animations on moving a robot (move left / right, go forward)

In reality it is a site with more complicated animations (loading ajax, loading images, multiple animations, etc ..)
that I currently manage with promises, but as the site evolves, the code of this part becomes a dish of spagettti.

This is the first time I do something like this, and I wonder if this is really a good idea, because this way of doing things seems really strange for me.
I have the impression that I will eventually find myself with insoluble problems.
In any case my current site becomes a real nightmare, because I have to change some animations, add new ones ...

Does this sample code look correct?
Should I change something there?

```js
const Root   = document.documentElement
  ,   gRoot  = getComputedStyle(Root)
  ,   moving = [ {T:-30,L:0},  {T:0,L:+30}, {T:+30,L:0}, {T:0,L:-30} ]
  ;
var RotateDeg = 0
  , RotateMov = 0
  , posT      = parseInt(gRoot.getPropertyValue('--PosT'))
  , posL      = parseInt(gRoot.getPropertyValue('--PosL'))
  ;
function F_1() // move forward
  {
  posT += moving[RotateMov].T
  posL += moving[RotateMov].L

  Root.style.setProperty('--PosT', posT + "px")
  Root.style.setProperty('--PosL', posL + "px")
  }
function T_L() // turn Left
  {
  RotateMov = (RotateMov +3) %4
  RotateDeg -=90
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + "deg")
  }
function T_R() // turn Right
  {
  RotateMov = (RotateMov +1) %4
  RotateDeg +=90
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + "deg")
  }
function R_0() // rotate to zero
  {
  RotateMov = 0
  RotateDeg = 0
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + "deg")
  }
function disableButtons(OnOff)
  {
  Bt_Tab_A.disabled = OnOff
  Bt_Tab_B.disabled = OnOff
  }
function* Sequence(Tab_fct)
  {
  for( let fct of Tab_fct) yield fct
  }

var iterator = Sequence([])

function nextSequence()
  {
  let command = iterator.next()
  if (!command.done) command.value()
  else disableButtons(false)
  }

Bt_Tab_A.onclick=_=>
  { 
  disableButtons(true)
  iterator = Sequence( [ F_1, T_L, F_1, T_R, F_1, T_R, F_1, F_1, T_R, F_1, F_1, T_R, F_1, R_0  ] )
  nextSequence()
  }
Bt_Tab_B.onclick=_=>
  { 
  disableButtons(true)
  iterator = Sequence( [ T_L, F_1, T_R, F_1, T_R, F_1, T_R, F_1, R_0 ] )
  nextSequence()
  }
robot.addEventListener('transitionend',  nextSequence )
```

```css
:root {
  --turn  : 0deg;
  --PosT  : 110px;
  --PosL  : 90px;
}
#robot {
  font-size   : 16px;
  width       : 30px;
  height      : 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align  : center;
  line-height : 1.8em;
  transition  : all .5s linear;
  transform   : rotate( var(--turn) );
  position:fixed;
  top : var(--PosT);
  left: var(--PosL);
}
```

```html
<div id="robot">R</div>

<button id="Bt_Tab_A"> Sequence A</button>
<button id="Bt_Tab_B"> Sequence B</button>
```

Tips and advice are welcome;)

Comment: No, it's not fine. Unless you need to directly control generators, you will want to use `async`/`await` instead. And you still should use promises for the indivudual async steps, instead of calling back some master `nextSequence` function.

Comment: No, that `nextSequence` is a nightmare because it's a global state that you rely on everywhere. Promises are much cleaner. You can just put the animation functions that return promises in an array, [and run them sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823708/1048572). Or just write a `function sequenceA(){ await Forward(); await Forward(); await TurnLeft(); await Forward(); … }`. Much simpler than anything with generators.

Comment: For simplicity, you might consider 
(1) each sequence instruction to specify a complete vector (direction and distance)
(2) turns to be made automatically rather than having to code them yourself. 
For example, your Bt_Tab_A sequence might be `Sequence(['U_1', 'L_1', 'U_1', 'R_2', 'D_2', 'L_1', 'U_0'])`. 
It would be fairly trivial to parse out each instruction into its *direction* and *distance* components then act on them. This isn't really an answer to the question as it stands but if you were to ask another question ...

Comment: Well, it certainly sounds like an interesting project.

Comment: The principle of what I described above might still be useful (to someone), namely to form sequences of multi-parameter instructions. My suggestion uses strings but you could equally use an array of objects or functions with bound-in params. The approach would be generally applicable, not just to a robot graphic.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 your idea assumes that we can establish a list of actions that are common to all objects, except this is absolutely not the case

Comment: I don't think I have made that assumption but there again I know very little about your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I feel like Promise is the way to go.

In my own rule of thumb (beware, it's opinionated):

- Use promise when you need to execute async operations *sequentially*.
- Use generator function when you need to generate result *when* you need it.

In your snippet, all you need to do is to have the animations run *sequentially*, not *when* you need it.

Besides, you will notice you have multiple functions that are dependant on the current state (result) of a single variable (i.e., `iterator`). What's bad about this is that when there's a bug in between your sequence, you will take more time and effort to debug the situation because one change in one function might affect the other functions. You also have a global `transitionend` event listener that is quite consufing at the first glance.

In short, using generator functions, the flow of sequential operations is hard to understand.

The approach below is using async/await. Only `Sequence` and `nextSequence` methods are modified (comment explanations inside). Every operation is contained within its own function scope. Reliant of global variables is reduced:

*(Sorry I formatted the code to my code style when I wrote them)*

```js
const Root = document.documentElement;
const gRoot = window.getComputedStyle(Root);
const moving = [
  {
    T: -30,
    L: 0
  },
  {
    T: 0,
    L: +30
  },
  {
    T: +30,
    L: 0
  },
  {
    T: 0,
    L: -30
  }
];

let RotateDeg = 0;
let RotateMov = 0;
let posT = parseInt(gRoot.getPropertyValue('--PosT'));
let posL = parseInt(gRoot.getPropertyValue('--PosL'));

function F_1(){
  posT += moving[RotateMov].T;
  posL += moving[RotateMov].L;

  Root.style.setProperty('--PosT', posT + 'px');
  Root.style.setProperty('--PosL', posL + 'px');
}

function T_L(){
  RotateMov = (RotateMov + 3) % 4;
  RotateDeg -= 90;
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + 'deg');
}

function T_R(){
  RotateMov = (RotateMov + 1) % 4;
  RotateDeg += 90;
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + 'deg');
}

function R_0(){
  RotateMov = 0;
  RotateDeg = 0;
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + 'deg');
}

function disableButtons(OnOff){
  Bt_Tab_A.disabled = OnOff
  Bt_Tab_B.disabled = OnOff
}

async function Sequence(Tab_fct){
  // Disable buttons before start
  disableButtons(true);
  
  for (let fct of Tab_fct)
    // Run the animation one by one
    await nextSequence(fct);

  // Reenable buttons before end
  disableButtons(false);
}

function nextSequence(fct){
  return new Promise(res => {
    // Move event listener here so that they dont depend on a global one.
    // Use { once: true } to run this callback only once
    window.addEventListener('transitionend', res, { once: true });
    
    // Run the animation
    fct();
  })
}


Bt_Tab_A.onclick = () => {
  Sequence([F_1, T_L, F_1, T_R, F_1, T_R, F_1, F_1, T_R, F_1, F_1, T_R, F_1, R_0]);
}

Bt_Tab_B.onclick = () => {
  Sequence([ T_L, F_1, T_R, F_1, T_R, F_1, T_R, F_1, R_0 ]);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --turn  : 0deg;
  --PosT  : 110px;
  --PosL  : 90px;
}
#robot {
  font-size   : 16px;
  width       : 30px;
  height      : 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align  : center;
  line-height : 1.8em;
  transition  : all .5s linear;
  transform   : rotate( var(--turn) );
  position:fixed;
  top : var(--PosT);
  left: var(--PosL);
}
```

```html
<div id="robot">R</div>

<button id="Bt_Tab_A">Sequence A</button>
<button id="Bt_Tab_B">Sequence B</button>
```

Comment: Why not make `currentTransitionCallback` a local variable?

Comment: @Bergi Actually, you're right. I'll update the answer, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, your code is very clear, and even shorter than mine! (despite the awful style;)) I think I will have to adapt it to my mix of different elements to animate, with their different resoles (`transitionend`, `ajax.success` ...) ps:`once:true` is a really plus for me!

Comment: Glad it helped @MisterJojo (even though I had to read through _your_ style ;)). Though you might want to check the browser support for `once: true`

Comment: it's not really mine : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style