# Applying a CSS rule using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following inside my custom css:-

```
img[src*="webmail"],img[src*="portal"],img[src*="website"],img[src*="CRM"],
   img[src*="object"],img[src*="Emailar"],img[src*="Contact"]
{
width:70px;
height:130 px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
}
```

now i want to do some calculation inside my javascript and then apply this css rule (mainly change the width from 70px to 50px):-

```
img[src*="webmail"],img[src*="portal"],img[src*="website"],img[src*="CRM"],
   img[src*="object"],img[src*="Emailar"],img[src*="Contact"]
    {
    width:50px;
}
```

so can anyone advice how i can apply this css rule using pure javascript (no jQuery will be preferred).

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to add a classname to these images instead of targeting them by their source?

Comment: @adr5240 yes possible

Comment: add a class to the rule, such as `.width-50`, then apply that to the image.

Comment: @MaximeLaunois the link you provide will be selecting items based on ids

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn can you please explain this in more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you add a class to these images.

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("{className}");
for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.width = "50px"
}
```

Feel free to add a `debugger` into the loop to play with individual items but this should do what you want.

Comment: but this code `var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("{className}");
for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.width = "50px"
}` did not change the images width

Comment: Can you post your HTML or explain what happened? I created this very simple version that does work: https://jsfiddle.net/d8a345vk/

Comment: ur appraoch worked on all the browsers i tried IE-11,chrome & firefox

Comment: Thanks for marking it and no worries mate! Just happy to help

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use a variable css. see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

```
:root {
  --ImgWith  : 70px; 
}

img[src*="webmail"],
img[src*="portal"],
img[src*="website"],
img[src*="CRM"],
img[src*="object"],
img[src*="Emailar"],
img[src*="Contact"] {
    width        : var(--ImgWith);
    height       : 130px;
    margin-top   : 0px;
    margin-right : 0px;
    margin-left  : 0px;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
const Root = document.documentElement

// ...

Root.style.setProperty('--ImgWith', '50px')
```

Comment: wow no way, I didn't know you could A. Create css variables and B. Update them dynamically with JS

Comment: @TheMuffinMan and C. Read them. My last exemple =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825817/is-it-ok-to-use-a-generator-function-to-replace-a-promise-management

Answer (score 1):

Using classes would be better, but if you want to apply this css rule using javascript , you can select the images with [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), loop through them and modify their style :

```js
document.querySelectorAll(
  'img[src*="webmail"],img[src*="portal"],img[src*="website"],img[src*="CRM"],img[src*="object"],img[src*="Emailar"],img[src*="Contact"]'
 ).forEach(elem => elem.style.width = '50px');
```

```css
img[src*="webmail"],
img[src*="portal"],
img[src*="website"],
img[src*="CRM"],
img[src*="object"],
img[src*="Emailar"],
img[src*="Contact"] {
  width: 70px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.buycpanel.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/webmail-e1474583020618.png" />
<img src="https://static3.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/portal-poster.jpg" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my case the `document.querySelectorAll(
  'img[src*="webmail"],img[src*="portal"],img[src*="website"],img[src*="CRM"],img[src*="object"],img[src*="Emailar"],img[src*="Contact"]'
 ).forEach(elem => elem.style.width = '50px');` did not change the width of the images +i did not get any error inside the browser console..

Comment: your code worked on Firefox but on IE i got this syntax error on `forEach(elem => elem.style.width = '50px')`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class such as `.width-50`, then add it to the the image.

In the example below the class gets added 2 seconds after the code runs.

```js
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('img').classList.add('width-50'), 2000)
```

```css
img[src*="placeholder"] {
  width: 70px;
  height: 130 px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

img[src*="placeholder"].width-50 {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

Comment: Off MyLawn thanks for the reply .. but i did not get what is the exact purpose for `img[src*="placeholder"]` and can i define the `.width-50` anywhere inside my css?

Comment: I used `img[src*="placeholder"]` because I am using a different url since you didn't provide a url containing any of the `src` attributes. You would just do the same thing I did using your `src` values that you provided.