# nodejs Worker_thread vs Promise.all or allSettled()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, worker-thread

I'm developing nodeJS server with Express.
As you all know, network process should be processed asynchronously.
And people usually deal with the result using callback function or Promise(async/await).

In my case, I need to send dozens of request to another server to get data.
but I think requesting these one by one is inefficient. So I found [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) which process several works asynchronously and get all results of works at once.
And I also found [worker_thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) in nodeJS, which results in similarly.

I can not figure out which one is proper and what is difference between them. 
Does anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since node is single-threaded, worker threads are meant to be used to prevent blocking the event loop, from a long and complex computational task that is time consuming. However, they are not good candidate for I/O intensive work.

From node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

> Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript
>   operations. They will not help much with I/O-intensive work. Node.js’s
>   built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers
>   can be.

So i think in this case you should probably use `Promise.all/allSettled`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is really helpful and clear to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Worker threads are for multi-threading cpu intensive stuff. Promise.all or Promise.allSettled are probably your best bets here. Which one you choose depends on how you want to deal with rejects/resolves.

This guy's answer will probably clear up the differences for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784198/9916277