# Resolve async-await promises inside for loops at once

Tags: javascript

I know if we have an async-await promise inside a for loop like this it will await for resolving the `Proceed` function on each of the iterations and after the last one we can see the log below the for loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
      await Proceed(guidePack[i]);
}
console.log("after for loop"); // we will see this only after all of the Proceeds are resolved
```

What I don't know is if there is a solution to resolve all the promises at once and leave the for loop to see the console log below it?

Let's have a look at the code I'm talking about:

```js
let guidePack = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let ProceedResolved;


guide(); // initiate proccess

async function guide() {
    StartCaptureKeyPress();
  for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
      await Proceed(guidePack[i]);
  }
  console.log('Guide is resolved!');
}


// this function executes speaker function, at speaker function we will resolve the promise
function Proceed(e) {

  console.log(e); // log A and B and C  
  speaker();

  return new Promise((resolve) => { 
    ProceedResolved = resolve; // resolve the Proceed when ProceedResolved() executes
  });

}

function speaker() {
  // resolve proceed after 6 seconds
    setTimeout(() => ProceedResolved(), 6000);

}

// Capture 'Enter Key' press
function StartCaptureKeyPress() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownCapture);
    function onKeyDownCapture (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('Enter Key Pressed')
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownCapture);
        event.preventDefault();
        for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){ ProceedResolved(); } // resolve promise here
      }
    }
}
```

if you don't touch anything it will log the `guidePack` elements one after another. and after them, you can see the console log saying `Guide is resolved!`. like this:

> "A"
>
> "B"
>
> "C"
>
> "Guide is resolved!"

if you press Enter key on your keyboard I want to resolve all remaining promises and leave the for loop to see the console log `Guide is resolved!`. So if after "A" log you press the Enter key we should see this:

> "A"
>
> "Enter Key Pressed"
>
> "Guide is resolved!"

I have tried to execute resolve multiple times but it doesn't work.
I can't do this without a hand please help...

Answer (score 0):

First you can store all not resolved results of all this methods in array and then you can use `Promise.all()`. It will resolve all promises inside this array. If any of this promise will return error then none promise of this array will be resolved.

```js
let results = [];
for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
      results.push(Proceed(guidePack[i]));
}
Promise.all(results)
 .then(...)
 .catch(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Promise.all or Promise.allSettled functions for more info have a look at

[Differences between Promise.all() and Promise.allSettled() in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784175/differences-between-promise-all-and-promise-allsettled-in-js/62547738#62547738)