# How to list and filter two request in one console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, rest

i'm trying to list my folders and subfolders but right now it only show me the folders not both

```
function getParserTypes (types, subject) {
  return types.map((type) => {
    return {
      id: type.entry.id,
      name: type.entry.name,
      grade: subject.grade,
      subject: subject.id
    };
  });
}
```

the first request call folders and with my second request call Subfolders

```
  const firstRequest = await axios.get(`${fox.url}/nodes/${firstFolderId}/children`, PARAMS);
  const secondRequest = await axios.get(`${fox.url}/nodes/${secondFolderId}/children`, PARAMS);


 const types = _(firstRequest.data.list.entries).filter((type) => !type.entry.name.includes('dog'),
      secondRequest.data.list.entries).filter((type) => !type.entry.name.includes('cat');
    
      const resourcesTypes = getParserTypes(types, subject);
    
      
      console.log("resourcesTypes",resourcesTypes)
```

my console display only my first Request not both

[image: JSON]

Comment: You should post an example of the JSON returned, and the `getParserTypes` function

Comment: I already updated it

Comment: Thanks, can you post an example of the JSON returned? you can do like this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(firstRequest.data));` post the returned string.
Also, tell what you want to accomplish, you used `lodash` filter to remove everything that contains `dog`, then `normal js filter` to remove everything that contains `cat`. Why you didn't use only lodash or only normal js? What one request has to do with the other?

Comment: i'm trying to call folders and his subfolders right now it show me only folders not both with my firstRequest i'm calling the folders

Comment: Please post the result of this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(firstRequest.data))`

Comment: i think i explain better in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630696/why-does-my-array-only-print-my-folders-and-not-my-subfolders-inside

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting both request. Since these are Promises, you can use `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784175/differences-between-promise-all-and-promise-allsettled-in-js) for difference. It returns a Promise too.

```
  const res1 = await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  );
  const res2 = await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2"
  );
  const res = await Promise.all([res1, res2]);
  console.log(res);
  -------- or --------------
  Promise.all([res1, res2]).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
  })
```