# How to synchronize an async map function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

I have a async map function but want it to execute synchronously because I need the output of the first statement to be used within the same loop. But the map runs asynchronously even with await statements, can you please help understand why this happens.

My use case if to insert a record into mongodb if not present and update it if present in a loop.
The data exists in the db but find fails within the loop but works outside.

My code:

```
        const doSomethingAsync = () => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(Date.now());
                }, 1000);
            });
        };

        await Promise.all(
            modelVarients.map(async varient => {
                console.log(`varient: ${varient._id}`);
                console.log('1');
                const onlineDevice = await Device.findOne({
                    model: varient._id,
                });
                console.log('2');
                await doSomethingAsync();
                console.log('3');
                await doSomethingAsync();
                console.log(JSON.stringify(onlineDevice));
                await doSomethingAsync();
                console.log('4');
                return varient;
            })
        );
```

Logs I get:

```
varient: 8 pro
1
varient: note
1
varient: iphone x
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
null
null
null
4
4
4
```

But what I expect to get:

```
varient: 8 pro
1
2
3
<actual response from db for 8 pro>
4
varient: note
1
2
3
<actual response from db for note>
4
varient: iphone x
1
2
3
<actual response from db for iphone x>
4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Node.js native Promise.all processing in parallel or sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823653/is-node-js-native-promise-all-processing-in-parallel-or-sequentially)

Comment: use await modeVariants.reduce( async (...) => ) instead of map

Comment: @olkvin thanks, I will try to implement in my code

Comment: @EdwardRomero thanks for pointing me to a similar question, yes it helped me learn about reduce and how to chain promises, the answer below from sashee using async/await is also very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `modelVarients.map(async () => >...)` converts all the elements into Promises, which means they all start executing. Then the `Promise.all()` collects them and waits for all of them, that's why you can use this structure to wait for the `map` to finish. This is parallel processing.

What you need is sequential processing, which you can do with a `reduce`, like this:

```
await modelVarients.reduce(async (memo, varient) => {
    await memo;
    // all the other things
}, Promise.resolve())
```

`reduce` is similar to `map` in a sense that it creates a Promise for all the elements in the array, but there is a *current value* that is passed from one element to the other. In this case, it is the `Promise.resolve()` for the first one, the result of the first for the second, and so on. With the `await memo` you can wait for the previous result.

With `reduce`, the last element will wait for the previous one, which waits for the previous one, and so on, so there is no need for a Promise.all.

I've written articles about how [map](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-map-in-javascript/) and [reduce](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-reduce-in-javascript/) works with async functions, they will help you see the big picture.

Comment: Using `reduce` with an `async function` as the callback is a bad idea, it's inefficient and too easy to get completely wrong.

Comment: @Bergi can you elaborate why you think this is a bad idea, when I looked into reduce even the official docs has a simialar example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @Sai That's using `then` not `await`, and is chaining (few) different functions from an array instead of the same function on (many) items in the array.

Comment: In general, just use a `for … of` loop and `await` - much simpler, shorter, and faster.

Comment: es-lint discourages for ... of when this error: "iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations." https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax 
any thoughts?

Comment: @Sai My thoughts on that? es-lint (or rather, that specific configuration) is just wrong. The array iteration methods don't work with `await`, and `for … of` is idiomatic and well-supported in modern environments. You can of course use `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` as well if you want to make your linter happy.

Answer (score 0):

looks like You should *chain* Your promises, not running then in parallel with `Promise.all`