# Need Promise.all but without running in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

How do I make the last console.log line of the code snippet execute only after ALL the updateInkLevel functions finish executing?

```
  for (let i = 0; i < activeDevices.length; i++) {

    updateInkLevel(accessToken, deviceId, logIndex) 
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500)) // add a small sleep delay
  }
  console.log("everything completed")
```

updateInkLevel is an async function, returning a promise. I was thinking of using Promise.all, but that would run each iteration in parallel, which is not I want here. Here, I'm firing each iteration sequentially one at a time, with a small sleep delay before firing the next call.

I'm looking for something like Promise.all, but without running in parallel.

References,
[Is Node.js native Promise.all processing in parallel or sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823653/is-node-js-native-promise-all-processing-in-parallel-or-sequentially)

Comment: Why not `await updateInkLevel()`?

Comment: hmm.. maybe i could store all the promises returned by updateInkLevel in an array, and call promise all after the loop?

Comment: Doing (essentially) `Promise.all(allUpdateLinkLevels)` still runs in parallel.

Comment: @VLAZ Per the answer in the reference above, parallel or sequential is determined at time of creation. Promise all simply waits for them to resolve, regardless.

Comment: It's not *exactly* determined at the time of creation. It depends whether you start a new request before the old one completes. So if you do `request(); request()` that's firing two requests but `await request(); await request()` (or `request().then(() => reqest()`) will first wait for the first one then the next one. Any time you're **not** waiting for one promise to settle before making another, the operations will be parallel. Therefore, if you store all promises in an array, that's already non-sequential. `Promise.all` just gives you the convenience to know when all are finished or not.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500)) // add a small sleep delay
> ```

Don't do that.

You are **guessing** how long `updateInkLevel` will take

---

Just `await` the promise returned by `updateInkLevel`.

That will pause the loop until the promise resolves.

---

> I was thinking of using Promise.all, but that would run each iteration in parallel, which is not I want here.

Are you sure you don't want them in parallel? That would often be more efficient.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That's by design actually, updateInkLevel calls an external API. If I run everything too close together, it will overload that server. 

The sleep call, is meant to add some space between each call.

Comment: i don't really care how long updateInkLevel would take. But I do want to start next one as soon as possible.

Comment: @tinker — If you want to add space between calls then put a sleep function there **in addition** to waiting for the call to be resolved.

Comment: @tinker If the server is that easily overloaded, I'd suggest having some protection/delay mechanism there as well. Otherwise, you're open to denial of service attacks if a malicious party decides to just fire a lot of calls.

Comment: @Quentin if I do that, the total running time is longer. We would be waiting for each call to complete fully before the next one can begin.

Comment: @vlaz good suggestion which I will definitely relay to then. But in the mean time I can't call in parallel. 2000 calls in parallel would lead to huge percentage of 500 response from the server.

Comment: @tinker — You explicitly said they shouldn't run in parallel! (And browsers have a limited number of HTTP requests they'll allow to go to any one given server at a time, so they'll get put in an internal queue anyway)