# Async Await in map changes sequence

Tags: javascript, async-await, array.prototype.map

The sequence in which the array should be displayed is getting disrupted

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const fooFunc = async (num) => {
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
    const data = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${num}`);
    const obj = await data.json();
    return obj;
  }
  return {
    name: 'test OBJ',
    des: 'just to see how will it display',
    num: num
  }
}
const arrNew = async () => {

  await Promise.all(arr.map(async (item) => {
    const newObj = await fooFunc(item);
    console.log(newObj, item);
    return item * 2;
  }))

}
arrNew();
```

I know this is because only some of the items are having a promise, but is there some way we can get that in proper sequence.

Js fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu0f3psa/2/

Comment: did you try to use `for await`

Comment: This has already been answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823653/is-node-js-native-promise-all-processing-in-parallel-or-sequentially).

Comment: @Mohammednaji, No I didn't, Thank you.

Comment: @alexanderdavide, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const fooFunc = async (num) => {
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
    const data = await consumeAPI(num);
    const obj = data.json();
    return obj;
  }
  return {
    name: 'test OBJ',
    des: 'just to see how will it display',
    num: num
  }
}
const arrNew = async () => {

  await Promise.all(arr.map(item => {
    const newObj = await fooFunc(item);
    console.log(newObj, item);
    return item * 2;
  }))

}

const consumeAPI = (num) => {
// here we resolve the promise after api consumed 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${num}`).then(response => {
           resolve(response);
      });
    })
}
arrNew();
```