# Await function with map

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am working on a project where am converting the pdf to png with some async functions. it is working fine for document at a time, but when it comes to bulk documents the map iteration moving to next element from the array before completing a async function (which contains two more async function inside it). below is my code.

```
await Promise.all(batchInputFiles.map(async item => {
                    const fileData: any = await uploadService.PdfToPng(item.pdfPath, 'batch', item.pageCount, item.parentPath);
                }));
```

Comment: AFIK as I know `Promise.all` runs all actions in parallel, you wanna use `for of`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086037/1129986). Also you might want to edit your question a bit to make it easier to understand what is it that you need help with.

Comment: What I want is, the for loop should not continue until the pdfToPng process get completed fully.

Comment: you need to return promise from map function. for eg: 
`await Promise.all(batchInputFiles.map(async item => { return uploadService.PdfToPng(item.pdfPath, 'batch', item.pageCount, item.parentPath);}));`

Answer (score 0):

1. `map` function need not be async function
2. You are not returning the `promise` from the `map` function.
   Try this:

```
await Promise.all(batchInputFiles.map(item => uploadService.PdfToPng(item.pdfPath, 'batch', item.pageCount, item.parentPath)));
```

Comment: Still the PdfToPng run only once.

Comment: the code is correct, I think you need some debug in case this code run only once

Comment: @shafnaz, it could be because of 2 things. One, there is only one element in the `batchInputFiles` array. Two, `uploadService.PdfToPng` has some internal state that prevents processing multiple files concurrently. 
Am I right?