# why multiple fetch run in sequence

Tags: javascript, fetch

So I was trying to run multiple fetch requests in parallel like this:

```js
    fetch(
        `http://localhost/test-paralell-loading.php?r`
    );

    fetch(
        `http://localhost/test-paralell-loading.php?r`
    );

    fetch(
        `http://localhost/test-paralell-loading.php?r`
    );
```

But they are unexpectedly running in sequence:

[image: fetch request running sequentially]

Is this an HTTP 1.1 limitation?
How can I overcome it?

Update:

seems like that is on chrome, o firefox it behaves differently:
[image]

Is there something that can be made to improve the peformance on chrome browsers?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586421/11768882) answer your question?

Comment: @ArturoMendes The answer in your link states that `Promise.all will execute neither in parallel nor sequentially but concurrently`, whereas in this question the requests are being sent sequentially.

Comment: Does the server respond to multiple requests at the same time? I think maybe the grey section in the image is connection started which (I think) might mean that the fetch has started but the server hasn't yet started to respond.

Comment: @Fractalism that answer has many resources that explain the topic better than I can. Plus when executing JavaScript on the browser you depend on how many resources does the environment want to dedicate to your process

Comment: @BenStephens it does respond multiple requests at the same time, see update results for firefox.

Comment: @ArturoMendes that is not it. fetch requests run in background and are not limited by the calls of an `await`, also I updated the details and firefox seems to behave more in the way I would expected.

Comment: Looks like requests are in the **stalled** phase of the Connection Start. This could be for any of the reasons under **queueing**. See this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-preview

Comment: Show the full waterfall and see how many TCP connections are active to localhost. Assuming your server is using http 1.1.

Comment: Making three GET requests for exactly the same resource seems wasteful. My guess is that the browser is queuing them in the hope that the response can contain a cache header so it doesn't have to repeat the request for a second and third time.

Comment: Related to Bergi's comment, could you try adding stuff to the query string of the requests. e.g. `http://localhost/test-paralell-loading.php?r=1`, `http://localhost/test-paralell-loading.php?r=2` etc.?

Comment: .


Bergi was right!!!


Please post as answer and I'll accept it as solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[@bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) [answer here](https://#comment-133438922) the reason why Chrome was behaving like that:

> The browser is queuing them in the hope that the response can contain a cache header so it doesn't have to repeat the request

Answer (score -1):

Your request are running concurrently, it is just that some of them are in the **stalled** phase of the Connection Start. This could be because of any of the reasons under **queueing**. See [previewing a timing breakdown](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-preview).

- **Queueing**. The browser queues requests when:

  - There are higher priority requests.
  - There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
  - The browser is briefly allocating space in the
    disk cache.

You can see the difference between running concurrently or in series by looking at the waterfall in your browser network tab.

```js
const endpoints = [
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/',
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/',
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/'
]
function requestConcurrently() {
  endpoints.forEach(endpoint => fetch(endpoint))
}

requestConcurrently()
```

Waterfall for concurrent requests:

[image]

```js
const endpoints = [
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/',
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/',
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/'
]
function requestConcurrently() {
  endpoints.forEach(endpoint => fetch(endpoint))
}

requestConcurrently()
```

(Using the same URL):
[image]

Now in series example:

```js
const endpoints = [
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/',
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/',
  'https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/'
]
async function requestSeries() {
  for (const endpoint of endpoints) {
    await fetch(endpoint)
  }
}

requestSeries()
```

Waterfall for in series requests:
[image]

Comment: I dont think that is the reason. It is related with HTTP 1 for sure, because your requestSeries works only for HTTP2 servers. trying to do that with an http 1 server will just do as I described. 
However I cant figure out why if there is a limit of connections > 1 it would behave like that. I believe that chrome has a limit of 2, and firefox of 6.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding or misconfigured server.

Comment: it wasn't that,  Bergi  nailed the reason why it was behaving like that. there was no error in the javascript nor the server.

Comment: It behaves the same whether you request the same URL or not. Also, did you not see the bullet item **The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache.**

Comment: it behaves the same with the same url? no it doesn't.

https://imgur.com/OmSM8K0
not at least on latest chrome 110.0.5481.177

Also waiting for a response of a request to see if it CAN be cached is quite different to allocating space to cache.

Comment: @useless your requests are firing concurrently, you can see that in the waterfall. Have you tried running the series code? I also attached a new image of running them concurrently to the same URL.

You also have not made any real distinction between the reasons for the stalling phase of some of the concurrent connections. How do you know **waiting for a response of a request to see if it CAN be cached is quite different to allocating space to cache**? There is no way you can.