# How to make new Promise+then chain semantically inside old Promise+then chain, but not in closure?

Tags: javascript, promise

Suppose I have scenario like this:

1. Make request to post some data inside promise;
2. a) If response data is ok - finish Promise+then chain;

   b) If response data is not ok - make new Promise+then chain - go back to point #2.

and code like this

```
var _p;
function make_promise(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //get data 
        var data = 'some data';
        resolve(data);
    })
}


function handle_response(data) {
    var _p;
    if (data == 'some data'){
        console.log(data);
        //finish then chain
    }
    if (data != 'some data') {
        _p = make_promise()
            .then(handle_response);
    }
}

_p = make_promise()
    .then(handle_respone);
```

On each iteration when flow of execution goes on `b)` choise this code will create new promise inside `handle_response` function. 
Will this new promise replace old or it will saved in closure?
If new promise will be saved in closure how to avoid this? Not save new promise to _p variable?

Comment: Use Q or Bluebird like the rest of the Internetz

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Who says that he isn't already?

Comment: His sample code says that. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Maybe `var Promise = require('bluebird')` as usual, or in the browser build it does use `Promise` as well? What would be different if he did use Bluebird?

Comment: Promise constructor is ES6 not Bluebird, unless they have new syntax to match.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're actually looking for is

```
function getResponse() {
    return make_promise().then(function handle_response(data) {
        if (data == 'some data'){
            console.log(data);
            //finish then chain
        } else {
            return getResponse(); // repeat, recursively
        }
    }
}

var p = getResponse();
```

The imporant part is the `return` which makes the returned promise resolve with the result of the recursive call - that is, `p` will always only fulfill when the "chain" is "finished".

Comment: Recursive call also stores the data for each call, and consume memory. If we have a few calls it is all good but if we must make significant amount of calls this is not an option.

Comment: @Raf: What do you mean by "stores data for each call"? Notice that `handle_response` is asynchronous, and that it's tail-recursive so no additional memory is consumed.

Comment: I don't know what data is stored, I just make simple test, which show memory consumed. http://i.imgur.com/tjIOsT9.png?1 And of course 10000 calls it's not real work case. Just want to know how it works.

Comment: What promise implementation are you using? Of course every execution of code does consume memory, but [this pattern should not leak](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29931657/1048572).

Comment: Native Promise inside Google Chrome 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit)