# Using setTimeout to run a large task without blocking input, and using Promise to find out when the task is complete

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Currently, I have a function which is called to do a large task using many setTimeout's in order to not block page interaction.

Example code follows

```js
function runAsync(maxMs, throttle, func){
  var begin = window.performance.now();
  var cont = func(throttle);
  var end = window.performance.now();
  if (cont){
    var newThrottle = Math.ceil((throttle/(end-begin))*maxMs);
    setTimeout(function(){
      runAsync(maxMs, newThrottle, func);
    }, 0);
  }
}

a = 0;

function makeHuge(addNum){
  var target = 1000000000;
  for (var x = 0; x < Math.min(addNum, target-a); x++){
    a ++;
  }
  $('#result').text(a);
  return a < target;
}

$('#run').on('click', function(){
  a = 0;
  runAsync(16, 100, makeHuge);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="result"></span><br/>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

As you can see above, setTimeout is used to do a long-running task without blocking user interaction. The called function, `func`, must return a boolean which says whether or not to continue doing the action. The throttle value is used to keep the execution time of `func` below `maxMs`, which, if set to 16, represents something like 60fps.

However, using this setup, I cannot figure out how to incorporate the new Promises to let me know when the `runAsync` task is finished, or if it failed.

Comment: It should probably be noted that isn't truly async at all, it's just deferred until the thread is free, and then it blocks.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like web Workers http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: @adeneo You are absolutely right. I just meant to use the word "async" in the function title to try to say that it is trying to be as async as possible in browser Javascript.

Comment: Well, no, going about this route isn't *completely* without merits. It's not async in the same sense, but at the very least, it will allow you to perform a complex operation without web workers, while still allowing frequent interactions with the UI. Web workers would probably be the best solution, but I haven't looked into how reliably consistent they are cross-browser. Also be aware that some libraries may have resolved this issue.

Comment: @Katana314 The problem is that I can't rely on HTML5, since I might be supporting old browsers

Comment: @user24984 Okay, then you're going about it pretty well. But, you will need to structure any function like `makeHuge` differently. You have to have it only do a very small "unit" of work, and save a function state for its next run. I could imagine having it receive an object from which it sets `x` to `1`, then next run sees x is 1 and increments to 2. You could probably also run it multiple times until you see that a certain amount of time has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give two solutions, as there's a trade-off between speed and being idiomatic in your case.

## Best performing solution

`setTimeout` has terrible error-handling characteristics, in that errors always end in web console, so use try/catch around everything to pass errors to `reject` manually. I also had to refactor a bit:

```js
function runAsync(maxMs, throttle, func){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function again(){
      try {
        var begin = window.performance.now();
        if (!func(throttle)) return resolve();
        var end = window.performance.now();
        throttle = Math.ceil((throttle/(end-begin))*maxMs);
        setTimeout(again, 0);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    }, 0);
  });
}

a = 0;

function makeHuge(addNum){
  var target = 1000000000;
  for (var x = 0; x < Math.min(addNum, target-a); x++){
    a ++;
  }
  result.innerHTML = a;
  return a < target;
}

run.onclick = function(){
  a = 0;
  runAsync(16, 100, makeHuge)
  .then(() => result.innerHTML = "Done!")
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
};
```

```html
<span id="result"></span><br/>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

Quite ugly, with a `Promise` constructor and try/catch muck, but there's a clean alternative.

## Most idiomatic solution

With a promise-returning `wait` helper to tame `setTimeout`, use promises throughout:

```js
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function runAsync(maxMs, throttle, func){
  var begin = window.performance.now();
  var cont = func(throttle);
  var end = window.performance.now();
  return (!cont)? Promise.resolve() : wait(0).then(() => {
    var newThrottle = Math.ceil((throttle/(end-begin))*maxMs);
    return runAsync(maxMs, newThrottle, func);
  });
}

a = 0;

function makeHuge(addNum){
  var target = 1000000000;
  for (var x = 0; x < Math.min(addNum, target-a); x++){
    a ++;
  }
  result.innerHTML = a;
  return a < target;
}

run.onclick = function(){
  a = 0;
  runAsync(16, 100, makeHuge)
  .then(() => result.innerHTML = "Done!")
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
};
```

```html
<span id="result"></span><br/>
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

Easy to read, and structured like your original code. Normally, this would be the clear winner.

However, be aware that there's a potential performance problem here if this is to run for a long time or an open-ended amount of time. That's because it builds up a long [resolve chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931657/918910).

In other words, as long there's more to do, every time `wait` resolves, it's with a new promise from a subsequent call to `wait`, and even though each promise gets resolved almost immediately, they all get `fulfilled` together with the same value (`undefined` in this case) only at the very end! The longer things run, the bigger the one-time jank may be when the last promise finally resolves with `undefined`.

While browsers *could* optimize this away, none do today AFAIK. See [long discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543590/918910).

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once, I would. Thanks for the thorough response!