# How can I traverse an promise object reference chain synchronously in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method that returns an promise of an object (by id) from a database asynchronously.

**function getObj(id){}**....returns promise of object

It may or may not have a reference to another object by storing its id.

**object.nextObjId**

I need to traverse the reference chain until I find the terminal object using this method.  Obviously I must wait for the promise to resolve before I can check for the next reference.

In synchronous code it would look like this:

```
function getTerminalObj(id)
{
    var obj = getObj(id);
    while(obj.nextRef)
    {
       obj = getObj(obj.nextObjId);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

How do I do this when getObj(id) instead returns a promise of an object?

Comment: did you check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925948/building-a-promise-chain-recursively-in-javascript-memory-considerations)?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong. I think you are asking "how to resolve a promise in a synchronized fashion". 
In a context of JS/NodeJS, there are a few options:

#### ES6: [Co.js / Generators](https://github.com/tj/co)

#### ES7: `await/async` [Async Functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/)

Both approaches need you to either:

- Have a relatively new version of JS implementation.
- Use babel to transform ES6/ES7 code to old ES5 code.

---

However, I would say you don't have to do this in a synchronized fashion. The following code may help:

```
function chain(obj) {
  if (obj.nextRef) {
    return getObj(obj.nextObjId).then(chain);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(obj);
}

getObj(id).then(chain).then(function(terminalObj) {
  // There is the terminal object.
  console.log(terminalObj);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot use anything above ES5 at this point.

Comment: "When using node 0.10.x and lower or browsers without generator support, you must use gnode and/or regenerator." from https://github.com/tj/co#platform-compatibility