# Is it wrong to have an infinite loop inside Vue.js instance in order to keep making predictions using Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tensorflow.js

I'm using Tensorflow.js to train and predict foods, the Web API to access my notebook webcam and Vue.js to create a simple page.

I have an infinite loop inside the `addExample()` method, the `while(true)`, which is responsible for asking the model to predict what is in front of my webcam every frame and re-render the result.

**I'd like to know if there is a problem in having an infinite loop inside a method in my Vue instance.**

```
async addExample() {
  const selector = document.getElementById('classSelector');
  const player = document.getElementById('player');

  // Get the intermediate activation of MobileNet 'conv_preds' and pass that
  // to the KNN classifier.
  const activation = this.net.infer(player, 'conv_preds');

  // Pass the intermediate activation to the classifier
  this.classifier.addExample(activation, selector.selectedIndex);

  console.log("Class '" + selector.value + "' added to the model");

  while (true) {
    if (this.classifier.getNumClasses() > 0) {
      const activation = this.net.infer(player, 'conv_preds');

      const result = await this.classifier.predictClass(activation);
      this.confidence = result.confidences[result.classIndex];
      this.label = this.foodClasses[result.classIndex].name;
    }
    await tf.nextFrame();
  }
}
```

This method is triggered when I click the training button, but inside the method it stays in infinite loop. But everytime I need to train the same object or a new one, I have to trigger the method again, which results in entering again in the same loop - but I think the old one keeps running.

```html
<button type="button" @click="addExample()">Train class</button>
```

In case you want to see the code in action, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/katth/3q4cvutw/19/)

**Edited**: Thank you for the answers. I was able to solve my problem in the way I was expecting. Now, when I trigger the `addExample()` function, I have only one loop running, instead of having the old ones. I'm saying this based on a very shallow analysis of my GPU utilization percentage in the Task Manager.

In the old way, when I triggered `addExample()` more than one time, I could see the GPU percentage utilization raising more and more.

[image]

Now, the percentage utilization  increases only one time.

[image]

This is the final code:

```
async addExample() {
  const selector = document.getElementById('classSelector');
  const player = document.getElementById('player');
  this.infiniteLoopControler += 1;
  const internalLoopControler = this.infiniteLoopControler;

  // Get the intermediate activation of MobileNet 'conv_preds' and pass that
  // to the KNN classifier.
  const activation = this.net.infer(player, 'conv_preds');

  // Pass the intermediate activation to the classifier
  this.classifier.addExample(activation, selector.selectedIndex);

  console.log("Class '" + selector.value + "' added to the model");

  while (internalLoopControler === this.infiniteLoopControler) {
    if (this.classifier.getNumClasses() > 0) {
      const activation = this.net.infer(player, 'conv_preds');

      const result = await this.classifier.predictClass(activation);
      this.confidence = result.confidences[result.classIndex];
      this.label = this.foodClasses[result.classIndex].name;
    }
    await tf.nextFrame();
  }
}
```

Thank you again for helping me!

Comment: You should try to focus your question on one specific problem. Right now, your text contains ~3 questions, the primary question is opinion-based and the "how to improve the code" is also off-topic, better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I actually have many questions and I tried to put everything in the same post, which is not ideal. Do you know if I can move a post from one Stack to another?

Comment: Modified my post to be more specific and concise about my concerns in my code.

Comment: Nice, it's a good question now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `await` inside a (infinite) loop. It is even better to use `await` than using `.then` as the stack trace does not need to be collected by the engine. For more information check out these topics:

- [Memory leak in nodejs promise design?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52427966/5627599) (Stackoverflow)
- [Asynchronous stack traces: why `await` beats `Promise#then()`](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces) (Blog post by a V8 developer)
- [Building a promise chain recursively in javascript - memory considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931657/5627599) (Stackoverflow)

---

If you need a way to stop the loop after it was started (when the button is clicked again), you could simply change your loop to check which iteration is currently active.

**Code Sample**

```js
let iteration = 0;

async function addExample() {
  iteration += 1;
  const myIteration = iteration;
  while (myIteration === iteration) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is a (very much) simplified example. Each time `addExample` is called the `iteration` variable is increased and the current iteration run is stored. When the button is clicked a second time, the condition of the first iteration will not be met anymore and the (first) loop will stop.

Comment: Thank you @thomas! It solved my problem. As I was suspecting, my code was not performant. Your approach fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to remove the `while(true)` is to use recursion instead.

```js
async addExample() {
  const selector = document.getElementById('classSelector');
  const player = document.getElementById('player');

  // Get the intermediate activation of MobileNet 'conv_preds' and pass that
  // to the KNN classifier.
  const activation = this.net.infer(player, 'conv_preds');

  // Pass the intermediate activation to the classifier
  this.classifier.addExample(activation, selector.selectedIndex);

  console.log("Class '" + selector.value + "' added to the model");


  const cb = () => {
    if (this.classifier.getNumClasses() > 0) {
      const activation = this.net.infer(player, 'conv_preds');

      const result = await this.classifier.predictClass(activation);
      this.confidence = result.confidences[result.classIndex];
      this.label = this.foodClasses[result.classIndex].name;
    }
    tf.nextFrame().then(cb);
  }

  cb();
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of this? IMHO your changes make the code less readable and do not improve it in any way. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It's not necessarily better, just another way to do it.

Comment: My post was a bit confusing and it may have led you to misunderstand me - so I editted. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use recursion (which is normally used to solve finite problems) in this case, because I really need to stay in an infinite loop. I think that staying in an infinite recursion can cause problems in stack memory.

Comment: As far as I could test right now, Promises don't recursively increase the call stack. Each `.then()` callback is invoked on the same depth.

Comment: I started trying your approach, but as soon as some issues related to accessing variables from outside the ```cb() ``` function - such as ```this.net``` and ```this.classifier``` - were raised, I decided to abort. And after thinking for a bit, your approach would still fall into the same hole that I was: when I trigger the ```addExample()``` multiple times to train the same object or a new one, I'm creating new infinite recursions while the old ones (that were activated in older trainings) are problably still running.